# Using reflection to instantiate a Java class from a .class file

Tags: java, reflection

I have a path to a .class file and i want to instantiate it from a running program.
I have to "load" this class but its classpath isn't in my .jar or my project, it is in a folder besides it (can't use Class.forName()).
How can i instantiate this .class ?

Comment: You need to use URLClassLoader

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can proceed as next:

```
File myFolder = new File("myfolder");
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{myFolder.toURI().toURL()}, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("my.package.Myclass", true, classLoader);
Myclass obj = (Myclass)myClass.newInstance();
```

First you create an instance of `URLClassLoader` using the context `Classloader` as parent, then you load the class using this new `ClassLoader` and finally you create an instance (here it calls a constructor with no arguments).

Comment: thank, works fine, but can i pass through the package name of "MyClass" called in Class.forName() ? Because i know the package but if someone wants to create an "add-on" for my program, his class must have the same package name than mine. I can get the class name easily (name of the .class) but can i get the name of its package ?

Comment: Well it depends on where your file _MyClass.class_ is located in _myfolder_ because you need to respect the directory and the package defined in the class file itself. If the package name is foo.bar, your file must be located at _myfolder/foo/bar/MyClass.class_ and you need to use "foo.bar.MyClass". If there is no package defined into the class then the class must be located directly under _myfolder_ and then you can indeed use "MyClass"