# Java reflection run test from classes in directory

Tags: java, reflection

I have an assignment which is supposed to teach the basics in GUI + Reflection. The program is supposed to run a test for a class and output if it succeeded or failed (How that looks is irrelevant). I'm currently using this to get the Class using reflection:

```
this.testClass = Class.forName(testClassName);
```

The issue is that the classes has to be within the project for it to function. Therefore I have to re-compile the program each time I want to run some other type of class that tests. What I need is to find out how to get the class dynamically with it being in a compiled version (.class) in same directory as the JAR file.

Thanks

Comment: Just an idea: Write the full class name into a property file and in your test, read the class name from the property file. Then you just need to change the class name in the property file, to run a different test. Also think about writing more then just one class name, so you can test multiple classes within one test run (if required).

Comment: I do already have the class name to be loaded. Question is, how do I get the class name by NOT having it in the project when I compile it to JAR and then get the class from having the compiled class versions in the same directory.

Comment: Property files are not part of the compilation. By using a property file, you compile your project once and then just change the value within the property file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *do not* have to recompile the reflective code to make this work. All you have to do is

- read the class name as a String from somewhere (configuration file, environment, command line flag)
- put the class you are trying to load on the classpath when you run the program. It does not have to be in the same jar file as the code that tries to load it. You can have many jar files (or class folders) on the classpath at the same time.

Comment: I already have the class name to be loaded. Question is, how do I get the class if I have the compiled versions in the same directory as the JAR file?

Comment: If the class is on the classpath, it will be loaded. What error do you get? Where exactly is the class file? How did you set the classpath and to what?

Comment: If it is *not* on the classpath (and cannot be added), maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452834/using-reflection-to-instantiate-a-java-class-from-a-class-file?rq=1